# Cannot open a python file in Ubuntu Terminal for Windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu

I'd like to open a python file (main.py) in my Ubuntu terminal for windows 10, how would I go about doing that? I've tried simply opening terminal and entering "python main.py" or "python3 main.py" but I get errno2 (no such file or directory).

I've tried changing the directory to C: to access the file, and I've tried doing python (filepath) of the file.

python3: can't open file 'main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

I expected for main.py to be open and ran in Ubuntu terminal

Comment: make sure that the bash terminal is open running in the same directory that contains the `main.py` file? With the terminal running you should be able to issue a `dir` or `ls` command and see the python `main.py` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like `main.py` isn't in the same directory you're currently in.

You may want to familiarize yourself with Bash, the shell which Ubuntu (and most Linux distributions) uses by default, and what you're likely using in your terminal.

To see the directory you're currently in, use `pwd`:

```
cball@cball:~$ pwd

/home/cball
```

To see what is in your current directory, use `ls`:

```
cball@cball:~$ ls
Desktop
Documents
Downloads
...
```

You can move into another directory `cd directoryName`:

```
cball@cball:~$ cd Desktop/
cball@cball:~/Desktop$ ls
cats.jpg
```

Here is a fairly gentle intro to linux: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-linux-basics

Once you know where your Python file is, you can run `python /path/to/main.py` or simply `python main.py` if you are already in that directory (or if main.py is in your `path` variable).

Good luck learning bash, linux, and python! :) Please let me know if you have any questions.